# How to refetch data in React Query in an action handler only when the data is stale?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, web, react-query

I know the regular refetching of the data in useQuery

```
const fetchData = async()=>{...}

// it starts fetching data from backend with this line of code
const {status, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
myKey, 
fetchData(),
{
  enabled: false,
}
);
const onClick = () => { refetch() }
```

I know this refetches data (makes an API call) everytime the onClick function is called. I only want the API call to be made if the data is stale like the when the useQuery function is called. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the data is stale and refetch accordingly.

```js
const ComponentX = ()=>{

    const {status, data, error ,isStale, refetch } = useQuery(
      key, 
      fetcherFn,
      {
        staleTime: 10 * 1000,
        enabled: false,
      }
    )

    const onClick = ()=>{
        if (isStale) refetch() 
    }

}
```

Comment: You are essentially trying to rerender the component everytime the onClick is called?

Comment: Since this is just a rerender, not a repaint on the browser, it shouldn't be a problem.
I can better help you if you can describe why you want to update data after a click has happened.

Comment: Its like a google search, everytime a new key is entered, an API call is made to fetch the results and update them on screen. 
My results are always same regardless of the keystrokes entered, so I am trying to make an API call once every 10 seconds when a key is entered.

Comment: It would be better to use refetch in this case. Let me send you another answer and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Its like a google search, everytime a new key is entered, an API call is made to fetch the results and update them on screen

Judging from this, you are likely looking for [lazy queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries#lazy-queries). It's important that you make the entered search string part of your queryKey.

```
const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('')

const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['query', search],
  queryFn: () => fetchQuery(search),
  enabled: !!search
})
```

With this, you don't need refetch() at all.